# Solve this differential equation $xy'(x)=y(ln(x)-ln(y))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xy'(x)=y(ln(x)-ln(y))$$
I am having a little difficulty here. Raising both to $e$ is correct ?

Comment: Rearranging brings the equation to $$dy=\ln\left(\frac xy\right)^\frac yx dx$$

Comment: I have come to this ,but not sure what to do after. Should I use substitution ?

Comment: Taking the hint given in the answer below, what if we guessed that $y=e^{g(x)}$?  How would that change the equation?

Comment: I come to a dead end. $g'(x)=lnx/x -e^{g(x)}/x$

Comment: I don't get the same result:  $$xg'(x)e^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)}(\ln x-g(x))\implies xg'(x)=\ln x - g(x)$$...

Comment: yes I did a mistake . So then I just have to solve the equation. When I find g(x) its a bit tricky to get y(x). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{hint}$

The general approach is to try lots of different transformations (this is what I do), you see something enough times you can be more direct. Try some elementary functions i.e.

$$
\begin{align}
y &=& Ax^{\alpha},\\
y &=& \mathrm{e}^{g(x)}\\
y &=& \sin(g(x))\\
y &=&.. ?
\end{align}
$$

etc etc.. one of the above allows the equation to become easier.